# Gradle sync Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I want to add an external library [GuillotineMenu-Android](https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android) in my application. I followed the steps given in the most upvoted answer to an existing question [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)
But I am facing error when I try to build project after step 6 i.e. when added dependency in `app/build.gradle` as  `compile project(":guillotinemenu")`. I tried all the stackoverflow links related to this error but its not working out. I have made a folder named libs in my app directory and copied the project folder **guillotine menu** there. Here is my 
**`build.gradle(Module:app)`** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sunshine.bbreaker.appet_i"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'

    // GuillotineMenu
    compile project(":guillotinemenu")
}
```

**settings.gradle(Project Settings)** file:

```
    include ':app', ':guillotinemenu'
project(':guillotinemenu').projectDir = new File('libs/guillotinemenu')
```

**build.gradle(Project:guillotinemenu)** file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}} allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}}
```

**settings.gradle(Project:guillotinemenu)** file:

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

**build.gradle(guillotinemenu)** file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yalantis.guillotine.sample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your guillotinemenu/build.gradle

Comment: I have already posted named as 'build.gradle(Project:guillotinemenu)'

Comment: Chek below. Your 'build.gradle(Project:guillotinemenu)' is a top level file. Your library must have a build.gradle inside.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I added the build.gradle file of the guillotinemenu library.

Comment: This build.gradle is a top level file. It can't work as library. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a structure like this:

```
projectRoot
  app
     build.gradle
  library
     build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

Each module has own `build.gradle` file. Also the `root/settings.gradle` defines all modules inside a project. Don't use another settings.gradle inside your module.

In **settings.gradle** :

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

In  **build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

In **library/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion ...
    buildToolsVersion ...

    defaultConfig {
        ....
    }

}

dependencies {
   //....
}
```

In **app/build.gradle** use your file but change:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    // GuillotineMenu
    compile project(":library")
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After your comment below, I think that in your case the library folder is the root folder of another project.
It means that you should refer to the **module** inside this project.

```
    projectRoot
      app
         build.gradle
      libs
         guillotinemenu
           build.gradle //top level file of guillotinemenu project
    -->>   module       
              build.gradle  //build.gradle of the module
```

So change the settings.gradle of your projectRoot.

```
 include ':app', ':guillotinemenu'
 project(':guillotinemenu').projectDir = new File('libs/guillotinemenu/module')
```

The module (libs/guillotinemenu/module) should have a `build.gradle` as the **library/build.gradle** described above.

Comment: the library guillotinemenu is already having its build.gradle file and settings.gradle file. It is using another library inside it which have just a build.gradle file. So, do you want me to change or delete settings.gradle of guillotinemenu project?

Comment: @brainbreaker It wasn't clear in the original question, sorry. I've updated the answer. If the guillotinemenu is another project you have to point the module inside this project